# scikit indices out of bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am quite new at scikit and I am getting indices out of bounds error while trying to fit a learner with a sampled training set

here is where the error occurs

```
def train_predict(learner, sample_size, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test): 


    results = {}
    start = time() # Get start time
    learner.fit(X_train[sample_size],y_train[sample_size])
    end = time() # Get end time

    results['train_time'] = end-start

    start = time() # Get start time
    predictions_test = learner.predict(X_test)
    predictions_train = learner.predict(X_train.head(300))
    end = time() # Get end time

    results['pred_time'] = end-start

    results['acc_train'] = accuracy_score(y_train.head(300),predictions_train)

    results['acc_test'] = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions_test)

    results['f_train'] = f_score(y_train.head(300),predictions_train)

    results['f_test'] = f_score(y_test,predictions_test)

    print "{} trained on {} samples.".format(learner.__class__.__name__, sample_size)

    return results
```

Here is the main code

```
    clf_A = GaussianNB()
    clf_B = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf_C = SVC()

    samples_1 = random.sample(X_train.index,len(X_train)/100)
    samples_10 = random.sample(X_train.index,len(X_train)/10)
    samples_100 = X_train.index

    results = {}
    for clf in [clf_A, clf_B, clf_C]:
        clf_name = clf.__class__.__name__
        results[clf_name] = {}
        for i, samples in enumerate([samples_1, samples_10, samples_100]):
             results[clf_name][i] = \
             train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)


     vs.evaluate(results, accuracy, fscore)
```

The erro is at line

```
---> 21     learner.fit(X_train[sample_size],y_train[sample_size])
```

it says

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: Did you try printing the length of `X_train` and value of `sample_size`?

Comment: I did, X_train is 36177 samples_1 is 361 and samples_10 is 3617

Comment: No I mean on which iteration is this error coming? what about `samples_100`?

Comment: In `train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)` method call you are passing `sample`, however `train_predict` method expects `sample_size`...

Answer (score 1):

Your error depends entirely on what X_train and y_train look like.

A common example that might fit your circumstances:
If these are pandas dataframe objects, then fixing your solution might be as simple as adding .as_matrix() as follows:

```
learner.fit(X_train.as_matrix()[sample_size],y_train.as_matrix()[sample_size])
```

Another quick thing you can check is that the number of rows returned by X_train[sample_size] and number of rows returned by y_train[sample_size] are the same. Please note that this is *not* the same as the following evaluating to true because X_train[sample_size] can have more columns than y_train[sample_size]:

```
len(X_train[sample_size]) == len(y_train[sample_size])
```

Providing information in your question as to how X_train and y_train were built or specifics about their type and shape would get you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
learner.fit(X_train[**0:sample_size**],y_train[**0:sample_size**])
```